# Story Identification - zombie movie on a ship

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror, zombie

I remember seeing part of a movie about a bunch of commandos or other "hard men" that storm a ship at sea only to be suprised by a hoard of zombies on the ship.  What is that movie?  This is driving me crazy...

Comment: *Pirates of the Caribbean, part XXI*, when the sequels finally get into the twentieth century...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hmmm, bad ships. Do you mean [*Deep Rising*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118956/) about a cruise ship being boarded by raiders/ pirates, only to find that all the passengers and crew are gone, attacked by a sea monster? Came out in 1998.

And there is [*Ghost Ship*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0288477/) from 2002. Also a ship without a crew, on which strange things happen as soon as people board it.

Comment: Aha, yes!  Deep Rising is the title - score!  So it was sea creatures instead of zombies.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

- Matango (aka Attack of the Mushroom People, 1963)
- The Ghost Galleon (aka Horror of the Zombies, Ghost Ship of the Blind Dead, El buque maldito 1974)
- Zombie (1979)
- Sexy Nights of the Living Dead (aka Erotic Nights of the Living Dead, Le notti erotiche dei morti viventi, 1980)
- Virus (1999)
- Cradle of Monsters (aka Mouryou no Yurikago, Manga series on 38th ed.)
- Twilight Syndrome: Dead Cruise (aka Towairaito shindorômu: Deddo kurûzu, 2008), Survival Of The Dead (2009)
- Triangle (2009)
- World War Z (a UN task force awaits zombies to emerge from the sea for 10 years)
- ... and Love Boat, sitcom of cruise ship zombies on cocaine.

Comment: Cleaning up the list, a number of these are pretty clearly not right, so I'm retracting my upvote. Plus, we should discourage scattershot list answers like this.

Answer (score 2):

That would be [*Survival of the Dead*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1134854/) not exactly my favorite one of the series.

[The trailer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wd6JhPY1ij0)

[image: Sailor about to get it.]

Comment: Hmm, not the one I am thinking of.  But _Survival of the Dead_ one looks like my kind of movie!  I saw (part) of the zombie ship movie I think in 2004 on cable/satellite.  I think it was made sometime late 90's or early 00's.  It starts of a kind of action/commando kind of movie, but then flips into zombie mode.  And then the zombs' have the upper hand over these gun-toting military guys.  Or something like that.  Maybe this was just a dream I had one day!  Thanks